# Wordpress plugin jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress plugin. I just used a grid loading effect jQuery on this plugin. This script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
new GridScrollFx( document.getElementById( 'grid' ), {
    viewportFactor : 0.4
} );
</script>
```

It is working on HTML, but when I am trying to work on plugin it just loading but not working. Where is the problem?

Here is my plugin code:

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: Custom Grid Loading Wordpress
Plugin URI: http://hotmovie24.com
Description: This plugin will more effective in your wordpress site. You can change color & other setting from <a href="options-general.php?page=ppmscrollbar-settings">Option Panel</a>
Author: Jean Rose
Author URI: http://somewebsite.url
Version: 1.0
*/

/* Adding Latest jQuery from Wordpress */

function cgl_wp_latest_jquery() {
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

add_action('init', 'cgl_wp_latest_jquery');

define ("CGL_VERSION", "1.0");

if ( ! defined( 'CGL_PLUGIN_BASENAME' ) )
define( 'CGL_PLUGIN_BASENAME', plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );

if ( ! defined( 'CGL_PLUGIN_NAME' ) )
define( 'CGL_PLUGIN_NAME', trim( dirname( CGL_PLUGIN_BASENAME ), '/' ) );

if ( ! defined( 'CGL_PLUGIN_DIR' ) )
define( 'CGL_PLUGIN_DIR', untrailingslashit( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) );

if ( ! defined( 'CGL_PLUGIN_URL' ) )
define( 'CGL_PLUGIN_URL', untrailingslashit( plugins_url( '', __FILE__ ) ) );

if ( ! defined( 'CGL_LOAD_JS' ) )
define( 'CGL_LOAD_JS', true );

if ( ! defined( 'CGL_LOAD_CSS' ) )
define( 'CGL_LOAD_CSS', true );


if ( ! defined( 'CGL_AUTOP' ) )
define( 'CGL_AUTOP', true );

if ( ! defined( 'CGL_ADMIN_READ_CAPABILITY' ) )
define( 'CGL_ADMIN_READ_CAPABILITY', 'edit_posts' );

if ( ! defined( 'CGL_ADMIN_READ_WRITE_CAPABILITY' ) )
define( 'CGL_ADMIN_READ_WRITE_CAPABILITY', 'publish_pages' );

if ( ! defined( 'CGL_VERIFY_NONCE' ) )
define( 'CGL_VERIFY_NONCE', true );

require_once CGL_PLUGIN_DIR . '/custom-post-type-grid.php';

function cgl_grid_custom_method() {
wp_enqueue_script(
    'cgl-custom-main',
    plugins_url( '/js/modernizr.custom.js' , __FILE__ ),
    array( 'scriptaculous' )
);

    wp_enqueue_script(
    'cgl-custom-classie',
    plugins_url( '/js/classie.js' , __FILE__ ),
    array( 'scriptaculous' )
);

wp_enqueue_script(
    'cgl-custom-colorfinder',
    plugins_url( '/js/colorfinder-1.1.js' , __FILE__ ),
    array( 'scriptaculous' )
);

wp_enqueue_script(
    'cgl-custom-gridScrollFx',
    plugins_url( '/js/gridScrollFx.js' , __FILE__ ),
    array( 'scriptaculous' )
);

wp_enqueue_script(
    'cgl-custom-imagesloaded',
    plugins_url( '/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js' , __FILE__ ),
    array( 'scriptaculous' )
);

wp_enqueue_script(
    'cgl-custom-masonry',
    plugins_url( '/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js' , __FILE__ ),
    array( 'scriptaculous' )
);
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cgl_grid_custom_method' );

function cgl_custom_style() {


wp_enqueue_style( 'cgl-custom-css', plugins_url( '/css/component.css', __FILE__ ), false, '1.0', 'all' );
}
add_action('wp_head', 'cgl_custom_style');

function cgl_custom_active() {?>

<script type="text/javascript">
new GridScrollFx( document.getElementById( 'grid' ), {
            viewportFactor : 0.4
        } );
</script>

<?php

}
add_action('wp_head', 'cgl_custom_active');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an error in your code, it is just a case of priority, when is your scripts loading.

It is always good practice to load custom scripts and styles dead last to make sure that these don't get overridden by other scripts and styles. To accomplish this, you'll need to set the `$priority` parameter in `add_action( $hook, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args )`. You'll need to set your priority very low, that is, giving the priority parameter a very high number, something like `999` which I usually use.

So change this

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cgl_grid_custom_method' );
```

to this

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cgl_grid_custom_method', 999 );
```

The same goes for the other action in your plugin

Comment: thank you so much for your answer and i did changed but not working yet. Any more options for solving this problem?

Comment: There is one thing though that I have picked up, your are making some scripts dependand on `scriptaculous`, but no where have you enqueued the `scriptaculous` script.